# Conditional props - Prop is mandatory but accepts different values depending on another prop

Tags: typescript, intellisense, typescript-typings

I am having an issue where I always want a prop to be mandatory but the values it accepts will depend on another prop. Here is an example:

```js
export interface ButtonManager {
  variant: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary';
  mode: 'manager';
}

export interface ButtonEmployee {
  variant: 'primary-dark' | 'primary-light' | 'secondary' | 'text';
  mode: 'employee';
}

type AcceptedProps = ButtonManager | ButtonEmployee

export const Button = ({
  mode,
  variant,
  ...props
}: AcceptedProps) => {
  // ...component renders styles depending on variant and mode
}
```

I am still unable to **exclude** the "*manager*" variants when the Button mode is set to "*employee*".

In other words, when the mode is set to "*manager*" Typescript still suggests `'primary-dark' | 'primary-light' | 'text'` as accepted props when these are only "*employee*" variants.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Works fine on my end - `<Button mode="employee" variant="primary" />` throws 2339, and `<Button mode="employee" variant="primary-dark" />` has no error

Comment: Huh, then I guess it has to do with my TS version or something?

Comment: It might be an IDE issue rather than a TypeScript issue. Try typing out a full component call (like I did above), rather than just looking at autocomplete, and see if it's detected as an error

Comment: I get the following error: `Types of property 'variant' are incompatible.
      Type '"primary" | "primary-dark"' is not assignable to type '"text" | "secondary" | "primary-dark" | "primary-light"'.
        Type '"primary"' is not assignable to type '"text" | "secondary" | "primary-dark" | "primary-light"'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Good, so it sounds like it's producing the TS error as desired when you try to mix an employee with a manager's colors

Comment: In [the playground](https://tsplay.dev/NByM4w) it suggests them all to me (when using [ctrl + space](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_intellisense)): https://i.stack.imgur.com/LytGL.png

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am still getting all suggestions like the comment above mentions though. Not the best DX for new devs in a project.